DllNotFoundException error given after trying to access the finder in my unity game
I followed this tutorial so that you can access the file explorer in runtime in my unity game, but I got these errors:

DllNotFoundException: StandaloneFileBrowser assembly: type: member:(null)
SFB.StandaloneFileBrowserMac.OpenFilePanel (System.String title,
System.String directory, SFB.ExtensionFilter[] extensions,
System.Boolean multiselect) (at
Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/StandaloneFileBrowserMac.cs:50)
SFB.StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel (System.String title,
System.String directory, SFB.ExtensionFilter[] extensions,
System.Boolean multiselect) (at
Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/StandaloneFileBrowser.cs:51)
SFB.StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel (System.String title,
System.String directory, System.String extension, System.Boolean
multiselect) (at
Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/StandaloneFileBrowser.cs:39)
OpenFile.OnClickOpen () (at Assets/Scripts/OpenFile.cs:30)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at
/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent/UnityEvent.cs:178)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at
/Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/artifacts/generated/UnityEvent/UnityEvent_0.cs:57)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute
(UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler,
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T]
(UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1]
functor) (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)

If anyone could explain what these errors mean and how I could disect them, that would mean the world.
I went to the lines that the errors were referencing but, I couldn't see what was wrong with them.

I would guess you're missing one of more dll files that are required required. Perhaps you missed a step in the tutorial or it is incomplete.

Are you on the correct platform the DLL supports? Note that DLLs are compiled for a specific platform (e.g. Windows Standalone vs UWP vs iOS etc) for specific versions and specific architectures (e.g. AMD vs x86 vs x64 etc)
